# Correct use of sapply with Anova on multiple subsets in R

Tags: r, apply, anova, sapply

I am trying to run a two-way ANOVA on multiple subsets of a data frame without having to actually subset the data as this is in-efficient

Example data:

```
DF<-structure(list(Sample = c(666L, 676L, 686L, 667L, 677L, 687L, 
822L, 832L, 842L, 824L, 834L, 844L), Time = c(300L, 300L, 300L, 
300L, 300L, 300L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 400L), Ploidy = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2n", 
"3n"), class = "factor"), Tissue = c("muscle", "muscle", "muscle", 
"liver", "liver", "liver", "intestine", "intestine", "intestine", 
"gill", "gill", "gill"), X.lipid = c(1.1, 0.8, 1.3, 3.7, 3.9, 
3.8, 5.2, 3.4, 6, 7.6, 10.4, 6.7), l.dec = c(0.011, 0.008, 0.013, 
0.037, 0.039, 0.038, 0.052, 0.034, 0.06, 0.076, 0.104, 0.067), 
l.arc = c(0.105074124512229, 0.0895624074394449, 0.114266036973812, 
0.193560218793138, 0.19879088899975, 0.196192082631721, 0.230059118691331, 
0.185452088760136, 0.247467063170448, 0.279298057669285, 
0.328359182374352, 0.261824790465914)), .Names = c("Sample", 
"Time", "Ploidy", "Tissue", "X.lipid", "l.dec", "l.arc"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L), class = "data.frame")
```

Coming across similar examples: [Anova, for loop to apply function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621188/anova-for-loop-to-apply-function) and  [ANOVA on multiple responses, by multiple groups NOT part of formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280491/anova-on-multiple-responses-by-multiple-groups-not-part-of-formula)

I can get close but I do not believe this is correct as it uses aov, as opposed to anova

```
x<- unique(DF$Tissue)

sapply(x, function(my) {
f <- as.formula(paste("l.dec~Time*Ploidy"))
aov(f, data=DF)
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

If i switch aov for anova, it returns an error message:

```
 Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
 no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "formula"
```

Long way around but which is CORRECT is as follows:

```
#Subset by each Tissue type (just one here for e.g.)
muscle<- subset (DF, Tissue == "muscle")
#Perform Anova
anova(lm(l.dec ~ Ploidy * Time, data = muscle))
```

However In the main data frame I have many tissue types and want to avoid performing this subset.

I believe the apply formula is close but need help on the final stages.

Comment: `sapply(x, function(my) { anova(lm(l.arc~Time*Ploidy, data=DF, Tissue==my)), simplify=FALSE)`. This uses a subset feature of `lm`

Comment: `anova` generates an ANOVA table from a fitted linear model (it doesn't fit the model itself; that's what `lm` and `aov` do). You have to use `anova(lm(...))` or `anova(aov(...))` to get an ANOVA table, as you did in your standalone example. `aov` is a wrapper for `lm` which prints its results in a more "traditional" ANOVA form (see the help for aov: `?aov`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers: few more tweeks and this works: sapply(x, function(my) { 
  anova(lm(l.arc~Ploidy*Time, data=DF, Tissue==my))
  }, simplify=FALSE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @user20650 and my comments above, I would suggest first using `sapply` with `lm` to generate your list of models, and then use `sapply` again on that list to generate your ANOVA tables.  That way the list of models will be available to you so you can get coefficients, fitted values, residuals etc etc.

```
x <- unique(DF$Tissue)

models <- sapply(x, function(my) {
  lm(l.dec ~ Time * Ploidy, data=DF, Tissue==my)
}, simplify=FALSE)

ANOVA.tables <- sapply(models, anova, simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: Got it working at the same time. Nice extra piece for the ANOVA.tables!

Comment: Thank you. It's just what I'm looking for.